# How to make unique string out of substrings?

Tags: java, string

When I concatenate two strings (e.g. `"q5q3q2q1"` and `"q5q4q3q2q1"`) I get string that have duplicate substrings `q5,q3,q2,q1` which appears twice.

The resultant string would be `"q5q3q2q1q5q4q3q2q1"` and I need to have each substring (`q[number]`) appear once i.e.`"q5q4q3q2q1"`.
Substring doesn't have to start with 'q', but I could set restriction that it doesn't start with number, also it could have multiple numbers like `q11`.

What could I use to get this string? If solution could be written in Java that would be good, otherwise only algorithm would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the concatenated string in groups and then use a set, if order of groups doesn't matter, or a dictionary if it is.

```
a = "q5q3q2q1"
b = "q5q4q3q2q1"

# Concatenate strings
c = a + b
print(c)

# Create the groups
d = ["q" + item for item in c.split("q") if item != ""]
print(d)

# If order does not matter
print("".join(set(d)))

# If order does matter
print("".join({key: 1 for key in d}.keys()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, this one is using regular expression. Concatenate the string and find all patterns `([^\d]+\d+)` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/T4NpLB/1)). Then add found strings to set to remove duplicates and join them:

```py
import re

s1 = "q5q3q2q1"
s2 = "q5q4q3q2q1"

out = "".join(set(re.findall(r"([^\d]+\d+)", s1 + s2)))
print(out)
```

---

Prints:

```
q5q2q1q4q3
```

Answer (score 0):

Some quick way of doing this via `java` as you asked in question:

```
        String a = "q1q2q3";
        String b = "q1q2q3q4q5q11";
        List l1 = Arrays.asList(a.split("q"));
        List l2 = Arrays.asList(b.split("q"));
        List l3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        l3.addAll(l1);
        List l4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        l4.addAll(l2);
        l4.removeAll(l3);
        l3.addAll(l4);

        System.out.println(String.join("q", l3));
```

Output:

```
q1q2q3q4q5q11
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of @DanConstantinescu's solution in JS:

- Start with the concatenated string.
- Split string at the beginning of a substring composed of text followed by a number. This is implemented as a regex lookahead, so split returns the string portions as an array.
- Build a set from this array. The constructor performs deduplication.
- Turn the set into an array again
- Concat the elements with the empty string.

While this code is not Java it should be straightforward to port the idea to other (imperative or object-oriented) languages.

```js
let s_concatenated = "q5q3q2q1" + "q5q4q3q2q1" + "q11a13b4q11"
  , s_dedup
  ;

s_dedup = 
    Array.from(
        new Set(s_concatenated
                   .split(/(?=[^\d]+\d+)/)  // Split into an array
            ) // Build a set, deduplicating
    ) // Turn the set into an array again
       .join('') // Concat the elements with the empty string.
    ;

console.log(`'${s_concatenated}' -> '${s_dedup}'.`);
```